# How to select this child div element for showing/hiding with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, coffeescript

When I click on the checkbox labeled "Magazine Citation", I want the div with the class 'boat_prize_award_radio_buttons' to be able to show/hide depending on if the checkbox is checked.  How do I make this work correctly?

Here is my current coffeescript/jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready ->
  $(".benefit_flag").change ->
    selected_obj = $(this).parent('div')
    if $(this).is(":checked")
      selected_obj.find('boat_prize_award_radio_buttons').show()
    else
      selected_obj.find('boat_prize_award_radio_buttons').hide()




<div class='outcome'>
  <ul>
    <li>etc.</li>
    <li>etc.</li>
    <li>etc.:</li>
    <fieldset class="inputs"><ol><li class="boolean input optional" id="person_magazines_attributes_12_benefit_flag_input"><input name="person[publications_attributes][12][benefit_flag]" type="hidden" value="0" /><label class="" for="person_magazines_attributes_12_benefit_flag"><input class="benefit_flag" id="person_magazines_attributes_12_benefit_flag" name="person[publications_attributes][12][benefit_flag]" type="checkbox" value="1" />Magazine citation</label>

    </li>
    <li class="radio input optional" id="person_magazines_attributes_12_citation_status_input"><fieldset class="choices"><ol class="choices-group"><li class="choice"><label for="person_magazines_attributes_12_citation_status_magic_was_cited"><input id="person_magazines_attributes_12_citation_status_magic_was_cited" name="person[publications_attributes][12][citation_status]" type="radio" value="Magazine was mentioned" />Magazine was mentioned</label></li>
    <li class="choice"><label for="person_magazines_attributes_12_citation_status_magic_was_not_cited_but_should_have_been"><input id="person_magazines_attributes_12_citation_status_magic_was_not_cited_but_should_have_been" name="person[publications_attributes][12][citation_status]" type="radio" value="Magazine was not mentioned" />Magazine was not mentioned</label></li></ol></fieldset>

    </li>
    </ol></fieldset>
    <div class='boat_prize_award_radio_buttons'>
      <p>My pilot fund award contributed to this outcome</p>
      <li class="radio input optional" id="person_magazines_attributes_12_boat_prize_award_contributed_input"><fieldset class="choices"><ol class="choices-group"><li class="choice"><label for="person_magazines_attributes_12_boat_prize_award_contributed_yes"><input id="person_magazines_attributes_12_boat_prize_award_contributed_yes" name="person[publications_attributes][12][boat_prize_award_contributed]" type="radio" value="Yes" />Yes</label></li>
      <li class="choice"><label for="person_magazines_attributes_12_boat_prize_award_contributed_no"><input id="person_magazines_attributes_12_boat_prize_award_contributed_no" name="person[publications_attributes][12][boat_prize_award_contributed]" type="radio" value="No" />No</label></li></ol></fieldset>

      </li>
    </div>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery parents() method. jQuery's parent() method travels only single level up the DOM tree.
Also, when giving classname as parameter in find() method of jQuery, you need to give . before class name.

Here is the script you want:

```
$(document).ready ->  
  $(".benefit_flag").change ->
    selected_obj = $(this).parents('div')
    if $(this).is(":checked")
      selected_obj.find('.boat_prize_award_radio_buttons').show()
    else
      selected_obj.find('.boat_prize_award_radio_buttons').hide()
```

Also, as per your requirement you should hide the radio buttons on page load by putting the code for that in *$(document).ready* function or using *display:none* property of CSS

Comment: thanks, the main problem with this answer is that I want a single parent - selecting multiple parents means I'm closing all children with a class of ".boat_prize_award_radio_buttons".  When I tried it with $(this).parent('div'), it didn't close anything.

Comment: I just figured it out: selected_obj = $(this).parents('div').filter('div.outcome') will give me what I need, thanks

Comment: You could also use selected_obj = $(this).parents('.outcome')